# How to add __len__ to sqlalchemy declarative meta?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have added the `__len__` method to the `User` class as shown below:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import func

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)

    def __len__() -> int:
        try:
            session = Session()
            return session.query(func.count(User.id)).scalar()
        except:
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()
```

Calling `User.__len__()` works fine.
However, calling `len(User)` yields the following error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'DeclarativeMeta' has no len()
```

I am not exactly sure how to adjust the class, such that `len(User)` is recognised as a valid statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally works, needed to call `__init__`.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import func

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"
    id = Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super(User, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        try:
            session = Session()
            return session.query(func.count(User.id)).scalar()
        except:
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()
```

And also instead of calling `len(User)`, I should have used `len(User())`. (Thanks @Cheukting for this)

Comment: Great that you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to find the length of the object of class `User` not the length of the `User` class itself?

If you do:

```
user = User()
len(user)
```

it will not have the same error

Comment: Same as before, `user.__len__()` would work then, but not `len(user)`

Comment: try `def __len__(self) -> int:` instead of `def __len__() -> int:`?

Comment: Ah yes, this + __init__ does the trick! Thank you very much!